# Java - list current RMI connections

Tags: java, rmi

I have a rmi server and rmi clients that are built using java.rmi.*. Besides the connection is protected by server-side SSL. How can I get list of current connections on server side?

Comment: What did you try so far? Show us your attempts.

Comment: @pc-shooter I found no solution to try.

Comment: Why do you think you need this?

Comment: @EJP For example administrator wants to check who currently uses server.

Comment: But it doesn't do that. Connections != users in RMI, because of connection pooling.

Comment: @EJP I don't understad you - can't I find out what clients from what hosts are currently connected to RMI server? It's so usual functionality.

Comment: You can find out the current connections as shown in my answer, but that isn't the same as the current users, because of connection pooling. You will get connections from RMI calls that were made many minutes ago. If that's good enough, so be it. It may not be. You need to examine your requirement more closely.

Comment: @EJP You are right. In details- A: some user started client program which connected to server (user host opened new net socket). B: User worked (rmi calls were made). C: User exited client program (user host closed net socket). I want to list of currently opened client hosts sockets.

Comment: It's not that simple. Connection pooling. Client program makes an RMI call, which opens a TCP connection. RMI call returns. Client stops doing RMI and goes and does something else. Connection stays open for some minutes. Is that a current client or not?

Comment: @EJP I understand you. Is the time from last rmi call till connection close known? Can this time be set?

Comment: Yes, see the RMI System Properties page. But setting it lower just to make an adminstration function easier is entirely the wrong thing to do. It's there for a performance reason, not to be taken lightly. What you need to do is sort out your actual requirement, not just fiddle around with things hoping it will all come right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I get list of current connections on server side?

From the point of view of RMI clients and servers there is no such thing as an RMI connection in the first place, so there is certainly no API to deal with them.

You could probably fudge something up via the socket factories but it wouldn't be pretty: you would have to extend both SSLServerSocket and SSLSocket and delegate heavily.

Comment: I think you are right and this is the only solution. Could you provide an example?

Comment: Sorry, too broad. It might be simpler for you to add the current client to a list at the beginning of every remote method implementation and remove them at the end. That would also be completely accurate, as opposed to showing meaningless connections.

Answer (score 0):

If you own the code that makes (or receives) the connections, you can create a Set that you add them to when they connect, and where you remove them from when you disconnect.

Comment: Not without surgery. There is no explicit connect or disconnect step in RMI.